# C++ vector:: _m_range_check when I run my code

Tags: c++, exception, vector, error-handling, range

This is my "ordered_array" header file code.
I've been struggling with `vector::_M_range_check out_of_range` error for some hours.
This header code has to be linked to the code [here](http://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/aclifton/cs133/files/assign1_test.cpp), then compiled and run. However, I have no idea what part is causing `out_of_range` here.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector <int> arr{};

class ordered_array{
public:
        ordered_array(int cap);
        ~ordered_array() {};
        int size();
        int capacity();
        void insert(int elem);
        void remove(int elem);
        bool exists(int elem);
        int* begin();
        int* end();
private:
        int maxsize;
};

ordered_array::ordered_array(int cap) {
                maxsize = cap;
}

int ordered_array::size() {
        return arr.size();
}

int ordered_array::capacity(){
        return maxsize;
}
void ordered_array::insert(int elem){
        if(arr.size() <  maxsize) {
                arr.push_back(elem);
                        if (arr.size() >= 2 ){
                                int t;
                                for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++) {
                                        if (arr.at(i) > arr.at(j)) {
                                        t = arr.at(i);
                                        arr.at(i) = arr.at(j);
                                        arr.at(j) = t;
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        else if(arr.size() == maxsize){
                return;
        }
}

void ordered_array::remove(int elem){
        if (arr.size() >= 1){
                for(int i=0; i < arr.size(); i++){
                        if (arr.at(i) == elem){
                                arr.erase(arr.begin() + i, arr.begin() + i +     1);
                                return;
                        }
                }
        }
                else if (arr.size() == 0){
                        return;
                }

}

bool ordered_array::exists(int elem){
        if ( arr.size() != 0){
        for (int i=0; i < arr.size(); i++){
                if(arr.at(i) == elem)
                        return true;
                }
        }    
        return false;
}
int* ordered_array::begin() {
        if (arr.size() != 0)
                return &arr.at(0);
        else
                return 0;
}

int* ordered_array::end() {
        if (arr.size() != 0) {
                return  &arr.at(arr.size());
                                            }
        else
                return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by running in a debugger to find out when and where in your code the exception happen.

Comment: By the way, should the vector `arr` really be a *global variable*? That makes no sense, since then you only have *one* vector no matter how many instances of `ordered_array` you have. Should it not be a *member* variable?

Comment: `&arr.at(arr.size());` in your end should throw.

Comment: Thank you. After I checked your reply and focused on that parts, so I debugged the code with Visual Studio. It successfully works!